# Cannot switch between windows of the same application

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys

I'm using Ubuntu 11.10 with Unity.

Switching between applications (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>) works, but switching between windows of one application (<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>) doesn't. Tried to assign <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> switching to another shortcut (<kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>, using system settings) but nothing works.

After install, everything was working fine.

I have `'` (apostrophe) instead of `` ` ``. To get that, I edited files in the */etc/X11/xkb/symbols*. Of course, if this matters.

Seems like there is a problem with assigning shortcuts using system settings. When I assign between windows of the same application to <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>, it still switches between different applications. No idea what's going on.

**UPDATE**: The problem is fixed.
I've been changing different settings of my keyboard, and one of the settings changed was XKBMODEL. I set it to "latitude" (thought it would fit better, that was really stupid). After I changed it back to "pc104", everything worked normally again.
Thanks everybody for your attention!

**UPDATE 2**: The `` ` `` symbol still needs to be in it's place for US layout. For Russian I was able to leave `'` assigned to "TLDE" button.

**UPDATE 3**: Seems like I have got the same problem with "Switch between windows of the same application immediately" (which is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> by default). It doesn't work, and assigning it to another shortcut doesn't help. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried editing the `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols/` back to `\`` instead of `'` ??

Comment: also according to [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1153309) `/etc/X11/xkb/symbols/` was moved to `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/*`

Comment: @rlemon I've changed it back to "key <TLDE> { [     grave,       asciitilde  ] };". Unfortunately, I didn't make any backups before modifying this file, so I'm not sure if this is what I need.

Comment: What keyboard layout do you use? The window switching is usually mapped to the button above the Tab key: for example, in the case of the Hungarian keyboard layout it is mapped to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>0</kbd>. So it depends on your keyboard layout, what key combination do you have to press to switch between windows. You could try to switch to an another keyboard layout, and see what happens.

Comment: I use English and Russian layouts, and both have "key <TLDE> { [ grave, asciitilde ] };". <TLDE> is the key above tab. Besides that, why do my attemps to assign windows switching to another shortcut fail?

Comment: OP answered own question either by adding the answer or by editing the question itself. I am flagging the post for closure. Regards,

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This was my problem too. `Alt+<key above tab>` didn't work to switch windows in the current application.

In addition, when i pressed and held down the `super` key to see the unity shortcuts, normally one would see this:

[image]

I'm assuming that is for a US keyboard? I stole the screenshot from [another post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114578/what-is-the-grave-button), and on my danish keyboard it now shows `Alt + Onehalf`.

But when I had this problem, I did **not** see the line pointed to by the red arrow!!!

So check if you see a keyboard shortcut for "Switch windows of current application". If you don't this is for you:

The fix was as hinted at above to change the `XKBMODEL` setting in `/etc/default/keyboard` where I changed from `XKBMODEL="microsoft4000"` to `XKBMODEL="pc105"`.

I did that and ran `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration`. Not sure this last step was required.

Then I needed to reboot.

Now it works.

Answer (score 9):

Suboptimal, but you can use the down arrow after <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Yes, that's an option, but <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>\`</kbd> would be a lot better.

Comment: No disagreement here.

Comment: @Amanda Thanks, I was unaware of this trick which works for me much better than the required feature, so your answer is to me superoptimal...

Answer (score 9):

You can change the short cut key of "switching windows" to <kbd>Alt</kbd> +<kbd>Tab</kbd>. Then you will be able switch between windows (not applications)

Exclusive for ubuntu 18.04 LTS - search keeyboard in settings and do the above change

Comment: No need to install any other packages

Comment: This works as 18.04! Up you go

Answer (score 7):

In Ubuntu 18.04.1 the default shortcut to switch between windows of same app is

### **`Alt + F6`**

[image: See Screenshot Here]

Comment: Use shift to go backward in order.

Answer (score 5):

In Ubuntu 18.04, at least with Vanilla Gnome3, press `Alt+Esc` for switching windows direct

Answer (score 1):

Just use

Switch within same app (alt+tilt) = [Alt] + [`]

Switch with another app = [Alt] + [Tab]

Comment: Yes, `Alt` + `\`` works great to switch between multiple windows of same app, thanks  :)

Comment: Your most welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

What about <kbd>[image]</kbd> then you <kbd>Tab</kbd> to your target window and <kbd>Enter</kbd>?

Comment: You have a enough reputation to post a comment.  So do not post comment in answer section.

Comment: @daisy, actually it is an answer... But I've made it as a question.. what is the problem?
Karel, thanks for your edition.

Comment: The behavior is the same as alt+tab in my ubuntu. Which is not the "common" behavior for alt+tab.

Answer (score 0):

Just press [<kbd>Super</kbd>](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LcvF.jpg) for 3 seconds and you will see the screen “Unity Shortcuts for Your Keyboard”:

[image: Unity Shortcuts for Your Keyboard]

There you will find your shortcut according to your keyboard and yes it's <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>The key above Tab</kbd>.