# What is the "Grave" button?

Tags: unity, shortcut-keys, terminology

The quick help of Unity (long press on the Super button) shows that *Switch windows of current application* can be triggered by Alt+Grave keyboard shortcut. What is Grave?

Here it is:
[image]

Comment: I don't think I've ever heard it referred to as just *grave*. The term [*grave accent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grave_accent) is more common, and can be considered the opposite of [*acute accent*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acute_accent). Both are related to the terms [*grave* and *acute*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/grave_and_acute) in linguistics.

Comment: @ændrük I took this term from the help screen of 12.04. See the screenshot that I added.

Comment: Does anybody know how this button is called in german?

Comment: @ moose: The "grave accent" can be translated as "Gravis Akzent/Betonung or Akzent Grave", though Germans (mainly) refer to it as "grave", since it is an adopted anglicism, and therefore one of many verbalized accepted/integrated words. Also it might have a slightly different phonetical touch to it (:

Answer (score 55, accepted):

This is usually the button immediately above the <kbd>TAB</kbd> on most keyboards.

For my keyboard - grave is actually correctly known as the <kbd>`</kbd> key - grave is also known as the back-tick.

In my travels I have seen the *Ubuntu "key above the tab"* to actually be the <kbd>§</kbd> or  <kbd>º</kbd>.  I'm sure there are many other similar characters on peoples keyboards.

Depending on your locality if you press and hold the <kbd>SUPER</kbd> to display the overlay, you should see the equivalent Grave key for your locality

for example:

[image]

<sub>(thanks Javier Rivera)</sub>

For my keyboard combination - <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> - gives you this switching capability (cycle through the windows group):

[image]

To use this key combination - let go of the *grave* without letting go of <kbd>Alt</kbd> and then repress *grave* to cycle through the windows group.

Comment: To be a bit more pedantic, "grave" is another name for backtick (i.e. the ` character); it has nothing to do with the placement on the keyboard and everything to do with it being superficially-similar to a grave accent.

Comment: But (I have heard) Unity does actually use "whatever key is above tab" on the current keyboard layout.  If backtick isn't there, it won't be the shortcut.

Comment: Confimed, there is a º in my keyboard above tab and it works.

Comment: @JavierRivera - thanks for the feedback - I've updated the answer with this.

Answer (score 18):

Additional information:
List of most common **Accents** and **Diacritical marks**

> ```
> acute       ´  
> breve       ˘  
> caron       ˇ  
> cedilla     ¸  
> circumflex  ^  
> dieresis    ¨  
> grave       `  
> macron      ¯  
> ogonek      ˛  
> tilde       ˜
> ```

---

**EDIT:**

**tilde** | **ˈtildə** | **noun**
an accent `˜` placed over Spanish **n** when pronounced **ny** (as in señor) or Portuguese **a** or **o** when nasalized (as in São Paulo), or over a vowel in phonetic transcription, indicating nasalization.

- the same symbol as a part of a URL.
- a similar symbol used in mathematics to indicate similarity, and in logic to indicate negation.

**ORIGIN mid 19th cent.:** from Spanish, based on Latin titulus.

*V.S*

**macron** | **ˈmāˌkrän; **ˈmak-; ˈmākrən** | **noun**
a written or printed mark `¯` used to indicate a long vowel in some languages and phonetic transcription systems, or a stressed vowel in verse.

**ORIGIN mid 19th cent.:** from Greek makron, neuter of makros ‘long.’

Source: [image: source]

---

Good question yossile (+1)up.
First of all, both differentiate in visual appearance `¯` *vs.* `˜`. Secondly, they are not exactly the same, depending on the language they where adopted by as shown in the dictionary example above, though both share a lot of similarities in executed usage, due to there common origin.

To my knowledge, the dictionary quote above is "not accurate/adequate", since one can find `˜` in archaic Greek philology (Heraclitus - Logos, Empedocles, Parmenides etc..)
as well. Although the Greeks adopted it from the [Phoenicians Alphabet](http://www.google.de/imgres?imgurl=http://www.phoenician.org/alphabet_phoenician.GIF&imgrefurl=http://www.phoenician.org/alphabet.htm&h=321&w=390&sz=15&tbnid=JCFkzSJ4xlOlxM:&tbnh=91&tbnw=111&prev=/search?q=phoenician%2balphabet&tbm=isch&tbo=u&zoom=1&q=phoenician%20alphabet&docid=-Oi-XUx3hz6M_M&hl=de&sa=X&ei=7YZsT_3yGeim4gTl2qm_Ag&sqi=2&ved=0CEAQ9QEwAQ&dur=381), which our language system today mainly is build on (Alphabet/Letters).

Comment: macron and tilde are the same. Is it true?

Comment: The reason I asked it is because in 12.04 I see the same visual character for both macron and tilde (actually tilde doesn't appear right). In 11.10 tilde looks like it should. Weird

Comment: Curious indeed. I still run 11.10, so i can not confirm if both are the same only for you, me/everyone else too, though it would be interesting to know of course. (Can someone else please confirm this!?) Right now i have three possible answers why this might be, but they are all hypothetical without more information, therefore not relevant. As long as both don't corrupt each other in usage it "hopefully" is only a minor cosmetic issue.

Answer (score 11):

"Grave" button is <kbd>`</kbd>, just next to <kbd>1</kbd>.

[image: Grave button]

Answer (score 0):

On German keyboard it's the <kbd>Ö</kbd> button.

Comment: Are you sure? It's supposed to be the key above Tab. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_keyboard_layout), that is not Ö.

Comment: Answer is not generic enough. It applies to a very small group of people regardless if it's true for said group.

Comment: -1 I use(d) a German keyboard and the default German keyboard layout and I can confirm, that this is not the case. The location of the keys for the shortcut mentioned in the question is the same as on US keyboards, but the key is labelled with a circumflex (`^`).

Comment: To close flaggers/voters: even though this answer seems completely wrong, it still attempts to address the question at hand. As such, it's a permissible answer per our rules. If you disagree with its content, vote it down and/or leave a comment.