# Don't know which masculine key is

Tags: shortcut-keys

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the “Grave” button?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114578/what-is-the-grave-button)

When I push and hold super key, there's showed the sorhtcuts, and in the swiching section is showed "Alt + Masculine" and I don't know which key is masculine key, can you explain me which key is?
Also, I don't know if it matters, but I'm Spanish, and I searched about masculine but I didn't found anything but man.
Thank you in advanced!

Comment: What is the purpose of that shortcut? example "Switch windows of current application".  I can give you the proper keyboard key/action if you tell me the action.

Comment: The action is "Switch windows of current application" =)
Also, if it doesn't means anything... is it possibly to be a bug?

Comment: It's probably an oops in automatic internationalisation.  You might file it as a bug.

Comment: I'm going to close this one - because you will get the same answers as the linked question.  Thanks.

Comment: My OS is English(UK), are you sure that it's a bug? I report it if you confirm me =)`

Comment: @CarlosSorianoSánchez - The text "grave" or "mascaline" etc depends on the keyboard layout (i.e. localisation) - so this is correct and is unlikely to be a bug.

Comment: most likely the key above the tab.