# Disable 'grave' button in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, guake

I want to bind in "guake terminal" grave <kbd>`</kbd> button to some action, but can't do this, always get exception that "Cannot bind global **grave** button".

Also I disabled <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd>

for "*switches windows of current application*" in unity, and now this shortcut works in "guake", but just <kbd>`</kbd> doesn't work still.

Maybe some suggestion or some ideas how to check what application uses this hot-key and deny it, to have ability to use in "guake". Thanks.

[Information about grave button](https://askubuntu.com/questions/114578/what-is-the-grave-button)

Comment: If you run `xev -event keyboard` and then press the key, what output do you get?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/sbojchuk/e34fd6cf2ed6bc60da17 - last three lines when I press 'grave'

Comment: and now, I get other output from above command - https://gist.github.com/sbojchuk/410dbb8a3816f512010a

Comment: so, after I try to bind in guake grave button (and get error) I get output like was in first comment, and after reboot, I get second output.

Comment: Same issue here. Sometimes it binds somtimes not. Is very annoying since I was very accustomed to use dead grave for guake.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I was able to bind on the dead grave key, the issue was due a keyboard language conflict.

You can try to binding on two different characters that represent the dead grave key, namely: `dead grave` and the ` character, and one of them will win.

The character that worked for me was the ` character.

Answer (score 0):

There are two keysyms for grave, `grave` and `dead_grave`, by default `dead_grave` is set to the ` key. xmodmap can be used to change it, and should be in Ubuntu by default (with arch install xorg-xmodmap).

To change it from the default `dead_grave` to `grave`, run:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode  49 = grave notsign grave notsign brokenbar notsign brokenbar notsign"
```

The rest of the values are various modifiers, e.g. the second one is shift.

If you want this to be permanent, create `~/.Xmodmap`, and then add just:

```
keycode  49 = grave notsign grave notsign brokenbar notsign brokenbar notsign
```

If there are any other dead keys you're having trouble with, run:

```
xmodmap -pke | grep dead
```

And it should give you a list of dead keys. Alternatively you could run:

```
xmodmap -pke >> ~/.Xmodmap
```

You will then have a full list of keyboard keys and their sym values in `.Xmodmap`, which makes it easy to change your dead keys and any other keys to whatever custom layout you like.

Comment: thank you, I will check, but for me, it works fine on Ubuntu 18.04 now. If I faced this issue again, will proceed with your approach.