# Incorrect behaviour for Super + dead grave (Switch windows of an application)

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys

I recently did a fresh install of Ubuntu 22.10.  I have noticed that the keyboard shortcut to *Switch windows of an application* used to be <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> (dead grave, under the ~) is not behaving as intended.  I even tried to switch to a different shortcut (replacing <kbd>Super</kbd> with <kbd>Alt</kbd>, for instance), but the problem persists as it is an issue with the command, not the shortcut.  It seems to work somewhat similarly to the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> combination.  I see how it works in Nautilus, but when I have two terminal windows open, and I then try to switch between them, it goes directly to one of the Nautilus windows.  Not the intended behaviour, of course.

On the other hand, the key combination <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, which is the default for *Switch windows of an app directly*, seems to work properly.  Although the behaviour is not the same, it may get me through while <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> is restored.  In the meantime, I will reassign the *Switch windows of an app directly* to a different combination as the original one requires two hands, while the convenient <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>`</kbd> only requires one.

Note: I have looked at other posts such as [Cannot switch between windows of the same application](https://askubuntu.com/questions/102657/cannot-switch-between-windows-of-the-same-application) and [Task Switcher brings all windows of an application to the front](https://Task%20Switcher%20brings%20all%20windows%20of%20an%20application%20to%20the%20front), but neither seem to be about the behaviour I am describing.